# How to access virtual host from the internet?

Tags: php, apache, ssl, xampp, virtualhost

I want to access my website via virtual host from the internet. For now, I am using the public IP address of my server to access my website. Here is what I am using (please see below).

> http://122.4.195.12:7777/site/index.php

1. Is there a way to access my virtual host from the internet? When I am accessing my virtual host from my internet (**https://mysite/site/index.php**) I am getting

> DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN error
>   mysite’s server IP address could not be found.

2. Is there a way to add a SSL when accessing my website via public IP address? When I change http into https I am getting

> ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR
>   122.4.195.12 sent an invalid response.
>   http://122.4.195.12:7777/site/index.php -> https://122.4.195.12:7777/site/index.php

Here is my Virtual Host Config:

```
<VirtualHost *:7777>
DocumentRoot "C:\xampp\htdocs"
  ServerName mysite
  <Directory "C:\xampp\htdocs">
    Require all granted
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:443>
     DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs"
     ServerName mysite
     SSLEngine on
     SSLCertificateFile "crt/scratchitsite/server.crt"
     SSLCertificateKeyFile "crt/mysite/server.key"
     <Directory "C:\xampp\htdocs">
        Require all granted
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
      </Directory>
 </VirtualHost>
```

Here is the host file of my server:

```
127.0.0.1       mysite
```

Comment: Thanx for editing, according to your newest info try what i mention below.

Answer (score 0):

**For question 1**

The easier way will still be registering a domain name, point it to your IP address, and setup your VirtualHost ServerName for it

The VirtualHost actually detecting the `Host` HTTP Header from server site, so the key thing here is:

> How to make the client browser send the `Host` header the same with you defined on server

For example, by using CURL you can force it to use the user definied `Host` header like this: `curl -H 'Host: mysite' 122.4.195.12:7777/site/index.php`

If you're using Chrome, you can try to use a browser extension, like [this](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/virtual-hosts/fbkigokjancnolojmhcgcfhgeeljolkh)

**For question 2**

You've enabled HTTPS on port 443 instead of 7777 in your Apache configuration

Which means you should access your HTTPS service like this `https://122.4.195.12:443/site/index.php` instead of this `https://122.4.195.12:7777/site/index.php`

Comment: How can I enable https of 7777?

Comment: I added the chrome extenstion what do I put in the source hose and virtual host?

Comment: You can't enable HTTP and HTTPS to a same port (e.g. 7777) at the same time, they must be different. And for the extension, put your IP address on the source host and the virtual host is your domain name (e.g. mysite)

Comment: So what will I do in my virtual host to enable https? can you show me I am a little confused

Comment: You already did it, in the section `<VirtualHost *:443>` has a `ServerName` directive in it

Comment: Oh ok now I have another problem when I access the site using :443 I am getting "privacy error NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID"

Comment: You might signed the SSL certificate yourself, to avoid this warning, the certification mush be signed from a verified CA. You can consider LetsEncrypt for this, but you'll need a validated domain name first

Comment: I used it but still not valid

Comment: We'll need more information in this case. What's the domain name you owned? And how LetEncrypt verify your ownership of the domain when signing the certificate for you?

And, if this is only for developing purpose, you can consider just simply ignore this warning.

Comment: I dont have a domain. but I need to access my site via https

Comment: As I said, to sign the SSL certificate from CA you'll need a valid domain name. And, the ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID is a warning, you can ignore it  from browser for developing purpose, see:
https://superuser.com/questions/1083766/how-do-i-deal-with-neterr-cert-authority-invalid-in-chrome

Comment: Simply Google for it, `letsencrypt xampp` and you'll get many tutorials for this. But again, you'll need a valid domain name before you try to apply LetsEncrypt SSL certificate to your site. For developing purpose, this is really not necessary, since you'll need to renew the LetsEncrypt certificate every 3 month when using it's free plan.

Comment: I have a subdomain now how can I install the ssl?

Comment: Try this: https://www.docketrun.com/blog/how-to-setup-lets-encrypt-for-apache-on-xamp-wamp-in-windows-vm/

Comment: Do install SSL manually into Xampp Apache, would be something like this: https://gist.github.com/nguyenanhtu/33aa7ffb6c36fdc110ea8624eeb51e69